# How to pass string from PHP page to myBB template / style?

Tags: php, mybb

I have a string on my PHP page called $psmoney that contains the value "9"- How do I call the string from inside my myBB template page in Admin CP>Templates & Style so it displays "9" on my page?

I have tried 
     '$psmoney'
but that  returns empty ''

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you on this problem. I'm also a MyBB user so maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

Put your code

```
$psmoney = "9";
```

in index.php, put it before

```
$plugins->run_hooks('index_end');
```

and then you can call

```
{$psmoney}
```

from your index templates

Comment: Thanks that works! But if I wanted to define another variable as $psmoney how do I do that? I have tried
    $psmoney = $thisvar;
but that dosent work?

Comment: Also, how would I define it so I can use it in ALL my templates and not just index templates? I have tried adding into the same place in global.php before the $plugins->run_hooks('global_end'); but dosent work? cheers

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: put it after code // Load language or after global start